# Firebase Firestore toObject() not working with data class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firebase firestore and convert toObject() with a data class. But it does not work as the object gets initialized but the field is not set.

This is very similiar to [Firebase Firestore toObject() with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633412/firebase-firestore-toobject-with-kotlin).
But I use already the proposed answer of using a data class and it is still not working.

**data class**

```
data class DataClass(
    var str : String = "default",
    var int : Int = 0,
    var bool: Boolean = false
)
```

Remark: Using a non-data class or changing the var names (in the code **and** the database) does not make any difference.

*I actually want to use more complex data/objects but stripped everything else to get it to work first.*

**code**

```
val clusterRef = db.collection("cluster")
clusterRef.document("e8efpRf2FBPwByWqaIRe").get(Source.SERVER).addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    Log.d(TAG, "${documentSnapshot.id} => ${documentSnapshot.data}")
    val cluster = documentSnapshot.toObject(DataClass::class.java)
    Log.d(TAG,"${cluster?.str} ${cluster?.int} ${cluster?.bool}")
    Log.d(TAG, "object: $cluster")
}
```

**Logcat**

```
e8efpRf2FBPwByWqaIRe => {str=HelloWorld, bool=true, int=42}

W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [k]: No setter/field for str found on class c.d.a.c.a
W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [k]: No setter/field for bool found on class c.d.a.c.a
W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [k]: No setter/field for int found on class c.d.a.c.a

default 0 false
object: DataClass(str=default, int=0, bool=false)
```

**Database**

[image: Database]

So the issue seems to be *No setter/field for available found*, but the field is there as e.g. `cluster.bool= false` works. There is no mention of explicit setter methods in the [Kotlin Reference - data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes) and I can not call `setStr()` [as mentioned here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties).

I am relatively new to Android development and Kotlin and suspect a very basic mistake, which I can not fix on my own even after spending a few hours crawling through SO and References.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something other than a boolean, by any chance? Maybe a string?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Added String and Int to test, but with no success. And the database screenshot as requested. @AlexMamo

Comment: If you use `Log.d(TAG, cluster.str)` right after `val cluster = documentSnapshot.toObject(DataClass::class.java)` is something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo added output as suggested, it prints out the default values.

Comment: What is `c.d.a.c.a` class?

Comment: @AlexMamo, this seems to be some internal identifier for the Data class. It changes depending on where I put the class definition.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @wonsuc I found no solution, in the end, I just filled in the object myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem with the same error message (No setter/field ...) and I solved this by adding get/set annotations in the data class, ie:

```
data class User(
    @get: PropertyName("first_name") @set: PropertyName("first_name") var firstName: String = "",
    @get: PropertyName("last_name") @set: PropertyName("last_name") var lastName: String = "",
    @get: PropertyName("email") @set: PropertyName("email") var email: String = ""
)
```

And then converted to object like this:

```
val user: User? = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
```

Comment: Thank you, problem was in syntax, I tried this:
val answerDocument = document.toObject(AnswerDocument.class)

Comment: For the email, the get & set should be unnecessary. In my case, I still needed it though, because my property is called "isCustomized" and the "is" is detected as one of Java's special words, like "set"-Property, "has"-Property and "is"-Property...